# Hello World program with spring 4, netbeans IDE

Tags: java, spring, jsp, netbeans, spring-4

This is my first attempt at spring and the question may seem to be very basic. I have spent lot of time trying to get it working but could not. From what I understand about spring there is a dispatcher servlet which routes all the incoming traffic to the appropriate controller.

As per the above understanding I have created a project using netbeans IDE. The code looks something like this.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

redirect.jsp

```
<%--
Views should be stored under the WEB-INF folder so that
they are not accessible except through controller process.

This JSP is here to provide a redirect to the dispatcher
servlet but should be the only JSP outside of WEB-INF.
--%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<% response.sendRedirect("index.htm"); %>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

    <!--
    Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
    for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
    define an explicit mapping for it.
    -->
    <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">helloController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <!--
    The index controller.
    -->
    <bean name="indexController"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
          p:viewName="index" />

    <bean name="helloController"
          class="controller.HelloController"
          p:viewName="helloWorld" />

</beans>
```

HelloController.java

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

/**
 *
 * @author rv814771
 */
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/helloWorld")
    public String sayHello() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

helloWorld.jsp

```
<%-- 
    Document   : helloWorld
    Created on : Nov 12, 2015, 12:40:16 PM
    Author     : rv814771
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Why does it not get redirected to the hello world page.

Comment: If this is your first attempt at Spring, ditch all the hand configuration, which is outdated and unnecessarily complicated. Use Spring Boot, which does all of that automatically. http://start.spring.io

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have redirect to 'index.htm'

```
response.sendRedirect("index.htm")
```

But controller is mapped to:

```
@RequestMapping("/helloWorld")
```